# O que significa "!!" em Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

Exemplo:

```
this.autenticator.logarExemplo(form.nome, form.senha,
usuario.idx, usuario.idy, !!usuario.login).subscribe(
  executar tarefas;
);
```

- O que seria o !! ?
- Esse simbolo pertence ao Typescript exclusivamente?
- Tem alguma relação com o símbolo || (ou) ?

Answer (score 1):

O '!!' é quando está negando uma negação. Exemplo

```
x = false;
console.log(!x) // true;
console.log(!!x) // false;
```

Não é exclusivamente do typescript, é o sinal de negação. 
Pode ser usado junto com condição OR (||) mais não existe alguma relação especifica entre eles.

Exemplo de uso de '!!' e ||:

```
if(!!x == false || !!x) {
    console.log('x é falso');
}
```

Comment: Muito legal! Mas qual a necessidade de usar ela então se estou basicamente dizendo que x será a mesma coisa que ele já é. E outra pergunta: !! é usado apenas para valores boleanos?

Comment: As vezes você precisa verificar uma estrutura qualquer como booleano, tipo uma string no Javascript, já que 'texto de qualquer tamanho' é verdadeiro e aspas duplas ou simples sem nada é falso. Para não passar toda a estrutura para a verificação você nega a primeira vez para tornar o valor booleano e consumir menos recursos e nega a segunda para não modificar o resultado esperado.